# How to solve problems with active list with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem trying to change the value of a class.
I have the follow:

**My HTML**. This is a Menu:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active">
<a href="home.php">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="correspondencia.php">Entrada</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**My JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav li').click(function() {    
    $('ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

I want to remove the class active from **Inicio** and add the class active to **Entrada** but when I do click it not change.

I do not what is the problem.

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/emLb9/), but you need to remember that changes to the dom made via javascript _do not persist through page loads / refreshes_.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$().on('click', function() {});` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Here us on
    $('ul.nav a').on('click', function(e) {
        // Do not go to the page ? 
        e.preventDefault() ;
        // Select only the active one (was not a problem but is proper)
        $('ul.nav .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** listen to the click on the `a` element. It's better. Example updated.
**EDIT 2:** Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KdaHh/
**EDIT 3:** Removed a wrong assumption thanks to Mickael comment.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Comment to the question solves the problem.
Read about `.click()` and get used to caching selections insted of searching again and again the same `ul` with the same class.

Comment: Did I said "your code won't work"? I said the answer is incorrect, that's different. First of all - [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/), and second - read comment under the question.

Comment: Ok for the click thing, I just read a little about it. In any case I frequently had problems while using click(callback) and never understood why. Thanks in any case for that, I'll edit the answer. About the cache thing, in that case it's not very usefull because the .active class is never the same.

Comment: [your fiddle with .click](http://jsfiddle.net/KdaHh/1/) still works. For triggering events you should use `.trigger('event name')`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I still had many problems using click that way, and always wondered why.

Comment: Probably, because you wrote something wrong :) it works in the same way... well, axcept some cases. Check my version here [http://jsfiddle.net/KdaHh/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/KdaHh/2/)

Comment: :) was sure to get this comment from you! Be sure I had many many times this issue (not in all browsers), and always solved it using .on().

Comment: Yes, very clean! But a bit verbose ;) You should post this answer?

Comment: Nope, no one needs this code here, the question author problem was in page reloading not in his script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were using Jquery.
check this out http://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
       $('a').parent().removeClass('active');
       $(this).parent().attr('class', 'active');
   }
});
```

This code snippet

```
$('a').parent().removeClass('active');
```

just removes all the `active` class from `li` of the anchor tag and below snippet adds `active` class to the current click

```
$(this).parent().attr('class', 'active');
```